# Parse information from Linux file to Windows using python

Tags: python, linux, windows, parsing

I am trying to parse some contents from my Linux environment and dump them into an excel file in my Windows environment using python.

`eg: foo/bar/myfile.txt` has some contents I want to stick to an excel file in my windows env `C:foo\bar\myfile.txt`

I know how to extract the information I need but I cannot find a solution to create a file in my Windows OS from my linux env in python. any little info helps. Thanks!

Comment: `fopen = open(my_file,"wb")` will open a file for writing ...

Comment: If your Windows partition is mounted and writable from within your linux OS, creating/writing to a Windows file should be the same as any other kind of file, try: `with open(r"C:foo\bar\myfile.txt", 'wb')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import sys
import subprocess


def env_key_values(host):
    """
    The subprocess.Popen will execute the env command on the remote
    Linux server then return the results.
    """
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", host, "env"],
                            shell=False,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    """
    Read each line from stdout selecting only the varname=value lines.
    Split the line on the '=' character. Use the first element as the 
    Linux environment variable name. Use the remaining elements as the value.
    yield the result.
    """
    for line in ssh.stdout:
        str_line = line[:-1].decode("utf-8")
        if "=" in str_line:
            key_values = str_line.split("=")
            values = "=".join(key_values[1:])
            yield (key_values[0], values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Open desired file in write mode, do not enforce EOL character.
    Create a CSV writer specifying the Windows EOL.
    Use \t character for delimiter as the specified file in the question
    used a .txt extension and the user wishes to import the file into Excel.
    """
    with open("file.txt", "w", newline=None) as fout:
        csv_out = csv.writer(fout, delimiter="\t" lineterminator="\r\n")
        csv_out.writerow(["VARNAME","VALUE"])
        for row in env_key_values("ldssbox01"):
            csv_out.writerow(row)
```